# Retrieve SqlCommand/OleDbCommand query after inserting parameters?

Tags: sql, parameters, oledb, sqlcommand, oledbcommand

Is there any way to access the prepared statement as sent to the SQL server?

```
            Dim params(1) As OleDb.OleDbParameter
            params(0) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
            params(0).Value = guiItemsGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ID").Value
            params(1) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@SavedValue", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
            params(1).Value = guiItemsGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Saved Value").Value

            Dim QueryString As String = "UPDATE Items SET [Saved Value]=@SavedValue WHERE ID=@ID"
            myDatabase.objAdapter.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(QueryString, DatabaseConnection)

            myDatabase.objAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddRange(params)
            myDatabase.objAdapter.UpdateCommand.Prepare()

            Debug.Print(myDatabase.objAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText)
```

I'm looking for a way to access the prepared query after the parameters have been added. After preparing the command, CommandText still contains the base query `UPDATE Items SET [Saved Value]=@SavedValue WHERE ID=@ID` even though the parameters have been passed.

I would find it useful to write a log of queries preformed by this chunk of code for debugging other areas of this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to log the query using the parameters functionality. I ended up reverting to creating the query in a string, then consuming said string:

`QueryString = String.Format("UPDATE Items SET [Saved Value]={0} WHERE ID={1}", SavedValue, ID)`

I then consumed that string for both the query and logging functions.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like that. I've built a method that can do the trick, it's not perfect, but it does help:

**VB .NET:**

```
Public Sub LogSQL(ByVal cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand)
    Dim pars As String = ""
    If cmd.Parameters.Count > 0 Then
        pars = " ["
        Dim a As Integer
        For a = 0 To cmd.Parameters.Count - 1
            pars = pars + cmd.Parameters(a).Value.ToString + ","
        Next
        pars = Left(pars, Len(pars) - 1) + "]"
    End If
    Log("SQL=" + cmd.CommandText + pars, LogNivel.INFO)
End Sub
```

This gives something like:

```
SQL=SELECT f1,f2 FROM table WHERE fx = ? AND fy = ? [20,35]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search around for a while and couldn't find to use that library to get a sql statement returned that had the parameters inserted. The best I was able to come up with was the SQL Server Profiler in sql server. If you turn it on and check the option `SQL:StmtCompleted` under the TSQL menu and `SP:StmtCompleted` under the Stored Procedures menu you will see event textdata columns like this:

***SQL:StmtCompleted***

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ap_test]
        @User_ID = N'testuser'
```

***SP:Completed***

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE User_ID = @User_ID
```

Since you were looking for a way to log your queries and their respective input parameters this might be useful- however, it would definitely be better if `UpdateCommand.CommandText` captured the inserted parameters. I will continue to see if a there is a solution out there as i have wanted this functionality several times myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
string commandString = UpdateCommand.CommandText;
foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in UpdateCommand.Parameters)
    commandString = commandString.Replace("@" + parameter.ParameterName.ToString(), parameter.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: To improve your answer try adding some explanation.